# Misalignment of column when i use str.split()

Tags: python-3.x, data-science-experience

I have a csv  that i read into notebook, i want to split the column  " Ad_name" into multiple column,  and rename some of the new column as Date.Platform and Types,with this i can then apply filter base on this column

click to download csv

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a1e36fbf6607b8cd542e2bb3ea0ef8d020240202133212/abd472

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vtz8b.jpg)

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(r"C:\\Users\\ME\\Desktop\\dataset.csv")
df1=df\["Ad_name"\].str.split("|",expand=True).rename(columns={3:"Date",4:"Platform",5:"Type"})

df1
```